# Using this in private java variables

Tags: java

I am working on something like this:

```
public class Job {
    private int priority;
    private String name;

    public Job(){
        priority=0;
        name="";
    }

    public Job(int p, String t){
        if (p>0){
            priority=p;
            name=t;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Wrong");
        }
    }


    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        if (priority>0){
            this.priority = priority;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Wrong");
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Which seems to be right.
I was wondering if I could simply do in setName for example, something like:

```
public void setName(String new_name) {
    name = new_name;
}
```

Is this right, or am I missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: It's 100% fine. Some find the first more readable, but it's really a matter of preference.

Comment: Why you shouldn't do that?

Comment: it's ok, as far as input variable has not same name. This is wrong: `public void setName(String name) {
    name = name;
}`

Comment: Actually, it's 90% fine... 10% less because of snake case :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `this` is usually preferred since it makes it clear to the programmer and who ever is reading your code that `this.foo` refers to the `foo` object (or method if `this.foo()`) in your class.

Although you can do it both ways as per your example, the second one might create some confusion with names since developers would now need to keep in mind that two different variable names will eventually be used to point to the same item.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to access private variables without using `this.` Most IDE's will indicate that fields are being used rather than local variables.

But using this is preferred way of writing constructors in order to avoid confusion as parameter names might have the same identifier.

---

This would be the case if:

```
public Job(int p, String t)
```

would be written as:

```
public Job(int priority, String name)
```

since `p` and `t` are not parameter names that you'd expect within a **public method declaration**.

Comment: Sorry for the late late edit, but I thought that the "avoid confusion" was not clear enough, feel free to roll back if this doesn't indicate what you meant by it.